# Conditional instantiation of an angular controller from within a template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So in Angular.js, I'm trying to do the following:

**index.html**

```
<div class="data-tabs-sms-scroll" ng-show="question.type == 'open'"
     ng-controller="AudioMessagesCtrl"
     ng-include="'/templates/audioMessages.html'"></div>
<div class="data-tabs-sms-scroll" ng-hide="question.type == 'open'"
     ng-controller="QuestionDetailCtrl"
     ng-include="'/templates/questionDetail.html'"></div>
```

**app.js**

```
ulizaApp.controller('AudioMessagesCtrl', ['$scope', 'QuestionResponse', 'ngAudio',
  function($scope, QuestionResponse, ngAudio) {
    console.log(
      'questionDetailCtrl', 
      $scope.$parent.question.id, 
      $scope.$parent.question.type
    );
  }]);

ulizaApp.controller('QuestionDetailCtrl', ['$scope', 'Question',
  function($scope, Question) {
    console.log(
      'questionDetailCtrl', 
      $scope.$parent.question.id, 
      $scope.$parent.question.type
    );
  }]);
```

**Firefox console output**

```
"questionDetailCtrl" 563 "multi" AudioMessagesCtrl.js:6:4
"questionDetailCtrl" 563 "multi" QuestionCtrl.js:6:4
"questionDetailCtrl" 564 "open" AudioMessagesCtrl.js:6:4
"questionDetailCtrl" 564 "open" QuestionCtrl.js:6:4
```

I would like the AudioMessagesCtrl to be instantiate only when question.type is equal to "open". And QuestionDetailCtrl to be instantiated whenever question.type is different from open.

For some reason this doesn't seem to be the solution.

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: try `ng-if` instead of `ng-show/ng-hide`

Comment: wow, looks like it's solving my issue. But in case why doesn't it work with ```ng-show/ng-hide``` ?

Comment: I agree with @VinayK . `ng-show/ng-hide` create the elements whether they are displayed or not, while `ng-if` actually controls whether or not something get's instantiated at all.

Comment: @Aaron is right. Inspect an ng-if and ng-show element, and you will see the difference.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know the difference. @VinayK, can you post your comment as an answer. Like this I can validate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-show/ng-hide` will render the dom and then decide whether to show/hide based on the condition.

`ng-if` renders the dom only if the condition is satisfied.

So, instead of `ng-show/ng-hide` try `ng-if`.

**Markup**

```
<div class="data-tabs-sms-scroll" ng-if="question.type == 'open'"
     ng-controller="AudioMessagesCtrl"
     ng-include="'/templates/audioMessages.html'"></div>
<div class="data-tabs-sms-scroll" ng-if="question.type == 'open'"
     ng-controller="QuestionDetailCtrl"
     ng-include="'/templates/questionDetail.html'"></div>
```